# How to include a link to reset password and register in Django views?

Tags: django, django-templates

In my Django view, I use the following tags for logging in and logging out:

```
<href="{% url 'login' %}">
<href="{% url 'logout' %}">
```

What are the analogous tags for registering an account and resetting the password?
Currently I am doing this which feels rather ugly:

```
<href="/accounts/password/reset/">
<href="/accounts/register/">
```

What's the proper way to do this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you need to install [`django-registration`](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/) to get these.

Then you can use:

```
{% url 'auth_password_reset' %}
{% url 'registration_register' %}
```

**EDIT**
For password reset you can use `password_reset`. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset).

Answer (score 2):

#### Password Reset

As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset), it should be:

```
<a href="{% url 'password_reset' %}">
```

#### Registration

This is usually supported by third party libraries. It seems you might be using the [django-registration default backend](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/8f242e35ef7c004e035e54b4bb093c32bf77c29f/registration/backends/default/urls.py?at=default#cl-40), in which case it is:

```
<a href="{% url 'registration_register' %}">
```

Comment: Why the negative votes? Is the information incorrect?

Comment: @init3 A very mature response. Do you really believe that I had to read your answer to frame my response? In fact, your __EDIT__ has the exact link that I posted. How did that happen? We are all trying to help here. If you check saquib-ali 's previous answer, I have helped him. So I know the context. 

I don't think this sort of downvoting is expected from a community like this. So I won't respond in the same token to your answer. Good luck with your Karma scoring!

Comment: Sorry, got a really mad morning today. It's not my normal behavior - sorry again. I'll edit your answer a little bit so I can remove my downvote.